# Pair and Sort the Columns in Desc Order

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

Hello I have the following data in my table:

[image]

Columns A to E indicate the year tag, and columns from F to J indicate the years. Each tag corresponds to a year. For the first line:

T1 -> 2004
T2 -> 2003
T3 -> 2003
T4 -> 2000
T5 -> 1986 (correctly ordered)

For the 9th Line as you can see:

L1 -> 1967
L2 -> 1977
L3 -> 1980
L4 -> 1985
L5 -> 1990 (ordered wrong)

What I want to do is to pair Columns A to E with the columns F to J and sort based on year, like follows:

[image]

(C4 should be B3, sorry for inconvenience)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the source data is in `Sheet1!A1:J10`, choose **Insert > Sheet** and put this formula in cell `A1` of the new sheet:

```
=let( 
  tags, Sheet1!A1:E10, years, Sheet1!F1:J10, 
  byrow( 
    sequence(rows(tags)), 
    lambda( 
      rowIndex, 
      let( 
        tagRow, transpose(index(tags, rowIndex)), 
        yearRow, transpose(index(years, rowIndex)), 
        { 
          transpose( sort(tagRow, yearRow, false) ), 
          transpose( sort(yearRow, yearRow, false) ) 
        }
      ) 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

The results look like this:

| Data |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | Result |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| T1 | T2 | T3 | T4 | T5 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 5 | 4 | T4 | T5 | T3 | T2 | T1 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| B1 | B2 | B3 |  |  | 8 | 9 | 10 |  |  | B3 | B2 | B1 |  |  | 10 | 9 | 8 |  |  |
| C1 |  |  |  |  | 42 |  |  |  |  | C1 |  |  |  |  | 42 |  |  |  |  |

See [let()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13190535), [byrow()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12570930) and [{ array expression }](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276).

Comment: Not all questions should be answered. If you found that a question doesn't include enough details, as it looks that it is because your comment, considering the reputation that you have consider to downvote and/or close as Needs details / unclear. Ref [answer]. [Kind reminder, voting is Important!](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4889/88163)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Considering that you are very active on the site I'm understanding that you might return later  (in few hours  / days) and vote accordingly to the state of the question at that time... that is perfectly fine. One of my current concerns about [webapps.se] is the high proportion of question from new users not getting any vote, not getting any update from the OP. This happens with all tags. Additionally other tags have a high proportion of questions having very few views. Anyway, thanks again for your reply.

Comment: Another day I will share with you some thoughts about "answerable questions".